# doxygen member grouping not working as in documentation

Tags: doxygen

According to the docs, this should be sufficient to grant documentation to the same members of a class

```
//@{
/** Same documentation for both members. Details */
void member1();
void member2();
//@}
```

My case is very similar. I have

```
  //@{
  /*! \brief comment blah blah
   *  \param one param
   *  \param two param
   *  \return return
   Foo &member1(MyEnum one, Foo & two)
   Bar &member2(MyEnum one, Bar & two)
   Baz &member3(MyEnum one, Baz & two)
   //@}
```

I tried but I get the description only on the first one. Am I missing something?

**Edit**: Ok, I tried their example

```
/** A class. Details */
class Test
{
  public:
    //@{
    /** Same documentation for both members. Details */
    void func1InGroup1();
    void func2InGroup1();
    //@}

    /** Function without group. Details. */
    void ungroupedFunction();
    void func1InGroup2();
  protected:
    void func2InGroup2();
};

void Test::func1InGroup1() {}
void Test::func2InGroup1() {}

/** @name Group2
 *  Description of group 2. 
 */
///@{
/** Function 2 in group 2. Details. */
void Test::func2InGroup2() {}
/** Function 1 in group 2. Details. */
void Test::func1InGroup2() {}
///@}

/*! \file 
 *  docs for this file
 */

//!@{
//! one description for all members of this group 
//! (because DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC is YES in the config file)
#define A 1
#define B 2
void glob_func();
//!@}
```

And it produces a result that is different from their [proposed result](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/examples/memgrp/html/class_memgrp___test.html). Again, I see no grouping, nor many other descriptions (e.g. the "A class" is not there). At this point I don't know. I am using the latest version.

Comment: Have you set DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC to YES?

Comment: @doxygen Please post it as an answer, so that I can upvote, confirm and worship you.

Comment: As a lateral note, I think there should be a comment in Doxygen documentation page that the feature will not work with the default Doxyfile, and that the option must be enabled.

Answer (score 16):

Remember to set DISTRIBUTE_GROUP_DOC to YES.

I post this as an answer as it appears @doxygen will not do it, credit where credit is due